# What is the best way to add the results of the Master thesis in the Latex report

Tags: listings

I am writing my `Master thesis` report. My thesis was research and development of a test data generator for a particular domain in an organization. The developed application will generate test data in XML and JSON format according to user requirements and design. These data can be very large.

For the demonstration of my results in Thesis report, I have designed a simple model and generating the test data for that design but still, the test data generated is pretty large so I have included them in the `Appendix` chapter of the result. It's taking around 20-30 pages, I have modelled the simplest design so there is no way for me to reduce the generated test data by simplifying the model further.

My professor has told me that this is not a good way of displaying the results. So I wanted to know what are the better ways of showing/visualizing your results/test data in the Master thesis report?

As I am writing the report in LaTeX format I have included them as `listings` in the `Appendix` section. Please provide me with some solution.

Comment: This sounds more like a general question rather than a question that is specific to TeX or LaTeX. As such it may be better to ask this at https://academia.stackexchange.com/ or another site about (technical/academic) writing.

Comment: FWIW I think I agree with your professor. While it is great to make data accessible to your readers, putting 20 to 30 pages of data into the appendix is not going to help anyone (especially if people read a printed version, but even if they have a digital version, copy-and-pasting can be painful). If the data you generate can be plotted or shown in some sort of diagram that might be a good idea (even if it only shows a usable cross-section or some aspects of your data). ...

Comment: ... Otherwise you probably want to focus on describing your data well enough in the thesis itself (maybe with small snippets of the data you generated) that your readers need only look at the actual data if they want to use it for something themselves (and not to understand it). Uploading the data to a a place with a persistent URL and linking to that URL might be enough.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have posted the question in another site. Actually, the main intention of the research was to generate these test data. I have provided the snipped of simple test data in the earlier section and example of bulk test data based on the scenario is provided in the `Appendix` section. Also, I have provided a brief graphical design in my `Results` chapter and provided link to Appendix section mentioning for complete test data refer to the respective section. So I am not entirely sure on how to display the test data in Graphical format in the Appendix section.

Comment: In my last thesis it was possible to hand in data like this electronically (e.g. a USB stick or a CD). If you do that and describe the important bits in the thesis itself, I think you should be fine

Comment: Thank you for the response. Yes, Actually I will handover the complete application code. The problem is I have 2 supervisors, one is from the company, and the other is from University. My company supervisor insisted me to add the test data in the Appendix section. But my University supervisor does not like that.

Comment: @BATMAN_2008 Try and get your supervisors to cooperate. Could you have one copy according to the University (who I assume will have the final say over your degree) and a similar one, but with an auxiliary document showing the test data, for your comany supervisor?

Comment: Thanks for the response. My external supervisor has agreed to the removal of that. Hoping everything would go well. Thanks again for the response.